# Google Structured Data Markup Helper - Opening Hours

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm trying to add some structured markup to my restaurant listing website using the Structured Markup Helper (highlighting tool) from Google.

When I highlight a restaurant's weekday and opening time, the markup helper tells me that the Day, Month and Year are "required" for an opening time (what?). When I attempt to generate the HTML anyway, the helper displays an error embedded in the markup:

```
<span itemprop="dayOfWeek" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/DayOfWeek"><td itemprop="name">Monday</td></span><td><strong itemprop="opens" content="Please insert valid ISO 8601 date/time here. Examples: 2015-07-27 or 2015-07-27T15:30">8:30am</strong> - <strong itemprop="closes" content="Please insert valid ISO 8601 date/time here. Examples: 2015-07-27 or 2015-07-27T15:30">Midnight</strong></td>
```

I can't work out the issue. Why would I enter a day/month/year for an opening time? An opening time relates to a weekday, not a day/month/year.

Seems like [this guy](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/280870-openinghoursspecification-and-dayofweek/) had the same issue, but the solution wasn't posted.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That strange. The only *required* tag I see is *name* (see screenshot below). 
Anyway I guess the main confusion for you comes from this phrase

> Please insert valid ISO 8601 date/time here. Examples: 2015-07-27 or
>   2015-07-27T15:30

Well in fact it doesn't mean you have to provide Day, Month and Year here. It just asks you to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date/time information. You can (and should in this case) use it only for time indicating.
E.g.

> "134730" in the basic format or "13:47:30" in the extended format

See nice [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) at Wikipedia about it.

[image: Markup Helper Screenshot]